# Pandas function explode does not work on this DataSeries

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-requests, explode

The pandas explode function doesn't drop the object elements into rows like it should.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import io
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data = payload)
response_text = response.text.encode('utf8')
fundingRate = pd.read_json(response_text,orient='columns',typ='frame')
fundingC = pd.DataFrame(fundingRate['data'])
fundingC = fundingC.T
fundingC = fundingC.astype(object)
fundingdataMap = fundingC['dataMap']
fundingdataMap = fundingdataMap.astype(str)
fundingdataMap = fundingdataMap.str.slice(start=10)
fundingdataMap.explode()
```

fundingdataMap DataSeries

https://www.pythonanywhere.com/user/armaniallie93/files/home/armaniallie93/fundingdataMap.txt

output

```
data    [0.07280400000000001, 0.013058, 0.01, 0.01, 0....
Name: dataMap, dtype: object
```

After setting the column elements as a string and slicing the portion I want, no error but it still doesn't produce the explode function correctly. Any insight to why?

Comment: post your data, please

Comment: You're required to post reproducible data. In any case we can't access `https://www.pythonanywhere.com/...`, it's behind a registration wall. Please just post a sample dict that illiustrates the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the error is quite simple. You have a dictionary which you are trying to explode, which would not work.

```
#Removing the first row with dictionary
df.iloc[1:].explode('data')
```

[image]

```
#Without removing first row
df.explode('data')
```

[image]

You will have to take a call on how you want to convert this dictionary into a list. That would require a `lambda` function.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Referencing to the code, I was able to convert the DataFrame into an object, define a column, convert the elements to a string and slice the elements I wanted. The explode function does not output an error but the column doesn't explode the way I want to. Any insight to this?

Comment: `"I was able to convert the DataFrame into an object, define a column, convert the elements to a string and slice the elements I wanted. The explode function does not output an error but the column doesn't explode the way I want to"` - Could you update your question to describe this?

Comment: Ok I get your take on it still being a dictionary, that's probably why still after no error, it doesn't explode correctly. How would you apply the lambda function to correctly convert it to a list with the right indexes?

Comment: you would have to post more data for me to suggest that. I would need complete examples of the dictionaries and the lists that are there in your data.

Comment: Please post your data in the question for my reference. A few complete examples would do.

Comment: I added the complete dictionary that was turned into a DataFrame column in the link above updated in the question